# REST: Должен ли ресурс в списке быть идентичным ресурсу, полученному напрямую?

Tags: rest

Пусть есть примерно такой ресурс:

```
GET collections/1/resources/1

{
    id:1,
    collection_id:1,
    foo:bar
}
```

Правильным ли с точки зрения REST будет по запросу

```
GET collections/1/resources
```

отдавать JSON вида

```
{
    //тут еще некоторые параметры типа limit,offset и т.п.
    collection_id:1,
    [
        {
            id:1,
            foo:bar
        },
        {
            id:1,
            foo:bar
        }
    ]
}
```

Вместо

```
{
    //тут еще некоторые параметры типа limit,offset и т.п.
    [
        {
            id:1,
            collection_id:1,
            foo:bar
        },
        {
            id:1,
            collection_id:1,
            foo:bar
        }
    ]
}
```

Лично у меня такое обращение с полем `collection_id` вызывает приступ агрессии и непроизвольные движения руками в поисках тяжелых тупых предметов. Я сказал, что это не по REST, но был осажен фразой "Если есть правила, регулирующие выдачу списков, покажи пожалуйста и тогда переделаем." Я долго рыл гугл, разбрызгивая слюни бешенства по своим трем мониторам, но не нашел таких правил. Единственное, что я смог привести в качестве аргумента, кроме своего опыта работы с десятком - другим api и опыта разработки трёх, это слова **Простота** и **Стандартизированность**, которые отрыл в какой то статье про REST. Прав ли я в том, что так делать не стоит, и если прав, то как мне донести до коллеги, что нельзя просто так взять и выкинуть из сущности поле?

Comment: первый вариант выглядит более логично

Comment: Вообще я первым делом в качестве компромисса добавил это поле и туда и туда (вернее второй вариант у меня уже был, так что надо было просто добавить одно поле. Но это, видите ли,не по ТЗ, сказал мне мой коллега, который пишет эти ТЗ. Просто непонятно, зачем выкидывать поле из сущности? Что оно плохого сделало? Люди понапишут каких нибудь `res.resources[0]`, а потом искать будут, с какой оно коллекции и куда это id коллекции делось

Comment: ну, это уже как бы избыточно, собственно как и второй вариант. Это только мое мнение). Опираться на него не стоит

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer, думаю, вы сможете прочувствовать зачем нужна эта избыточность, когда попробуете восстанавливать модели после получения данных из API ;)

Comment: @Darth, на самом деле вопрос намного шире. В общем виде проблема коллекций с REST осложняется в ситуации, когда каждый ресурс имеет не три поля, а тридцать. Вот тогда проблема отдачи полных/не полных объектов в коллекциях встает в полный рост.

Comment: У нас там и не три поля. Я привел упрощенный пример. Более того, коллекций у нас тоже ближе к 30, чем к 3, и почему-то только в двух из них использовано это "абстрагирование" поля

Comment: По моему это вопрос медицинского характера, а не технического. А так тут действительна теорема Бредора

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ на вопрос в заголовке: Да, должен.

Пояснение:

Одно из требований к REST это "Унифицированный интерфейс". Другими словами везде должно быть Единообразие. Если Вы выдаете 5 полей, для одного ресурса, то столько же нужно выдавать и в случае доступа ко всем ресурсам.

Много или мало информации решать не Вам! Для одного пользователя мало, а для другого может быть много. Но лучше вернуть информацию полностью, а пользователи сами извлекут что им требуется для работы. Если же боитесь падения скорости при отдаче всех ресурсов, то можно подумать об `pagination`. Это когда ресурсы за один запрос выдаются по N штук.

Список литературы:

1. [Что такое RESTful на самом деле](http://habrahabr.ru/company/hexlet/blog/274675/)
2. [Что такое REST?](http://www.restapitutorial.ru/lessons/whatisrest.html)

Comment: Вот-вот, спасибо) Пойду кину в коллегу вашим "Унифицированным интерфейсом". Правда я уже всё это говорил, немного другими словами